# redirecting excess power in fluctuating supply?

Tags: dc, generator

noob here. i have basic knowledge.
im trying to build a generator (with a universal motor) that first needs to direct up to 14.4v to a 12v battery.
after generating sufficient power, anything above 14.4v id like to have pushed out elsewhere.
so how do i fully utilise the initial power to recharge the battery, and how do i redirect any surplus through another circuit (AC)? because it concerns a wind generator, the power will hardly ever be constant
much appreciated

Comment: "anything above 14.4v" doesn't seem to make a ton of sense. AFAIK, generally you would use some kind of converter to output exactly whatever voltage is needed to charge the battery, with a varying amount of current.

Comment: You don't measure _power_ in _volts_. Understanding that is a good start.

Comment: @immibis no thats the thing. i expect more than 14.4v over time. it will vary too.

Comment: @pipe yeah i know that power is the product of potential x current already
so that wasnt helpful at all
you might also wanna mention watts for power when you think someone doesnt know this

Answer (score 0):

You need a buck converter to reduce the generated DC voltage to the 14.4 volts required for charging the battery. If you want AC voltage from the battery you need a power inverter.

You will probably not be able to use a universal motor as a generator without disconnecting the field winding and providing a separate field power supply. A 12-volt battery may or may not be sufficient to supply the required field current.

If you can get the universal motor to operate as a generator, you will find that it is not very efficient. Universal motors are not very efficient as motors and can not expected to be efficient as generators.

Comment: (putting aside your last point) my idea was to use a 12v battery to power the windings initially. the generator would then create power and in turn charge said battery. when fully charged and when the generator is self-sustaining, id like to direct all power to another circuit. is that perhaps a better solution than splitting?

regarding your last point, how much % would this motor generate compared to when powered by ac230v?

Comment: The best scheme for using the generator will depend on what you would like to power and how much generation and storage capacity you have. A Wikipedia article estimated universal motor efficiency as 30% to 75% depending on power rating. The maximum output will be similar to the power required to operate the motor with voltage proportional to speed. Efficiency will determine the mechanical input power required.